# "I was set" versus "I was sat"

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

In a television show I heard chef Gordon Ramsay say: "I was **set** at this table by the waitress." However it is also possible that he said: "I was **sat** at this table by the waitress."

For me as a foreigner it is impossible to distinguish the pronounciation of "set" versus "sat". Are native English speakers able to hear a subtle difference between the two?

It is clear to me that the meaning of the sentence is "I was **seated** at this table by the waitress." Now this may well coincide with the meaning of "set". Webster's Dicitionary gives as the first two meanings: (1a) to cause to sit; make assume a sitting position; (1b) to place in or on a seat. On the other hand, it is my understanding that "I was sat" -while officially incorrect English- is a familiar expression used in certain regions of England.

Is it possible that any such unofficial usage of the word "sat" finds its origin in confusion over the pronounciation of "set" and "sat" and/or the similarity in meaning (as both are related to sitting)?

What would be the correct present tense version of what Gordon Ramsay said?

Comment: What people say in passing cannot serve as a model of what's correct, only what's clear enough in daily exchange, ya know? In the Deep South, people will tell you to *set a spell* when they mean *stay seated*.

Comment: "I was sat [there]" is an incorrect, but commonly heard version of "I was sitting there", but "sat there by the waitress" uses the verb transitively.

Comment: My *place* was set at this table by the waitress.

Comment: For all his legendary swearing, I think Gordon Ramsey is relatively "well-spoken", so I would ***not*** expect him to use ***sat*** in the cited context (it's a *very* "low register" alternative to ***seated***). He being in the restaurant business, I think it's perfectly natural that he should use ***set*** (as a slightly less common alternative to ***put, placed***) even though most native speakers would probably use ***seated***. Don't forget that you ***set*** (or ***lay***) *the table* for diners, at home OR in a restaurant.

Comment: @KateBunting Nevertheless, it's good to see people at least trying to stick to the official rules, as published by the English Academy.

Comment: The TV chef's surname is spelled R A M S **A** Y.

Comment: @Michael Harvey. Thank you for pointing this out. I have adjusted my post accordingly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I like your answer best ! Indeed it seemed to me that someone like Gordon Ramsay would avoid the ugly and lower class "sat", and instead use a word like put or placed or seated. "Set" is correct English, because Webster's Dictionary says so.

Comment: I might have posted it as an answer if it weren't for the existing answer which baldly asserts that you did in fact hear ***sat*** because that's what Ramsey actually said. For all I know, that could be true, and the answerer might have listened carefully to a recording of the relevant program. Of course, sometimes people "misspeak" and accidentally end up articulating something other than what they intended. But I think if Ramsey really did say ***sat*** there, it would be ***clearly and emphatically*** articulated as a "facetious" usage (for him). Not likely, imho.

Answer (score 4):

> However it is also possible that he said: "I was sat at this table by the waitress."

Yes, that is what you heard.

> Are native English speakers able to hear a subtle difference between the two [sat, set]?

Yes: clearly.

> On the other hand, it is my understanding that "I was sat" -while officially incorrect English- is a familiar expression used in certain regions of England.

It is not incorrect English. You can say "seated" but that is slightly different from "sat".

> Is it possible that any such unofficial usage of the word "sat" finds its origin in confusion over the pronunciation of "set" and "sat"

No. I have said that native speakers make the distinction easily.

> and/or the similarity in meaning?

As set is no longer used to mean sit - no.

I sit, I sat, I have sat,
Passive: I have been sat at the larger table by the waitress.

OED

> **1b.** transitive. **With prepositional phrase as complement. To cause (a person) to be seated in a specified place or position.**
>
> 1650   T. Bayly Herba Parietis 124   *I like the seat no more than if he **had sat** me upon the stoole of sad repentance.*
>
> 2001   J. Coe Rotters' Club (2002) 18   *Take a few shop stewards, invite them upstairs, sit them round the conference table, make them feel important.*

Comment: Many English restaurants have a sign saying 'Please wait here to be seated'.